# Get total available system memory with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, memory, ram

Using PHP, I'd like to get the total memory available to the system (not just the free or used memory).

On Linux it's quite straight forward. You can do:

`$memory = fopen('/proc/meminfo');`

and then parse the file.

Is anyone aware of an equivalent method for Windows? I'm open to any suggestions.

**Edit: We have a solution (but StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question):**

```
exec( 'systeminfo', $output );

foreach ( $output as $value ) {
    if ( preg_match( '|Total Physical Memory\:([^$]+)|', $value, $m ) ) {
        $memory = trim( $m[1] );
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, and it's very slow, but it suits my need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455379/get-server-ram-with-php

Comment: Side note: PHP has a built-in memory limit, so the RAM size of the machine is not necessarily the RAM available to your script (unless you disable the memory limit)

Comment: systeminfo is horribly slow- probably not a good idea if script has user interaction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this via `exec`:

```
exec('wmic memorychip get capacity', $totalMemory);
print_r($totalMemory);
```

This will print (on my machine having 2x2 and 2x4 bricks of RAM):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Capacity
    [1] => 4294967296
    [2] => 2147483648
    [3] => 4294967296
    [4] => 2147483648
    [5] =>
)
```

You can easily sum this by using

```
echo array_sum($totalMemory);
```

which will then give 12884901888. To turn this into Kilo-, Mega- or Gigabytes, divide by 1024 each, e.g.

```
echo array_sum($totalMemory) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024; // GB
```

Additional command line ways of querying total RAM can be found in

- https://superuser.com/questions/315195/is-there-a-command-to-find-out-the-available-memory-in-windows

---

Another programmatic way would be through `COM`:

```
// connect to WMI
$wmi = new COM('WinMgmts:root/cimv2');

// Query this Computer for Total Physical RAM
$res = $wmi->ExecQuery('Select TotalPhysicalMemory from Win32_ComputerSystem');

// Fetch the first item from the results
$system = $res->ItemIndex(0);

// print the Total Physical RAM
printf(
    'Physical Memory: %d MB', 
    $system->TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 /1024
);
```

For details on this COM example, please see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php
- [MSDN: Constructing a Moniker String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: Win32_ComputerSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can likely get this information from other Windows APIs, like the [.NET API.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dotnet.php), as well.

---

There is also PECL extension to do this on Windows:

- [win32_ps_stat_mem — Retrieves statistics about the global memory utilization.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.win32-ps-stat-mem.php)

According to the documentation, it should return an array which contains (among others) a key named `total_phys` which corresponds to "*The amount of total physical memory.*"

But since it's a PECL extension, you'd first have to install it on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor (and possibly more suitable for SuperUser) distinction, but as it's come up for me in a recent windows service, I'll provide it here. The question asks about *available* memory, not total physical memory.

```
exec('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value 2>&1', $output, $return);
$memory = substr($output[2],19);

echo $memory;
```