# Caching large Array causes memory exhaustion

Tags: php, caching, file-upload, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to cache an array in a file and use it somewhere else.

**import.php**

```
// Above code is to get each line in CSV and put in it in an array 
// (1 line is 1 multidimensional array) - $csv 

$export = var_export($csv, true);
$content = "<?php \$data=" . $export . ";?>";
$target_path1 = "/var/www/html/Samples/test";

file_put_contents($target_path1 . "recordset.php", $content);
```

**somewhere.php**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
include_once("/var/www/html/Samples/test/recordset.php");
print_r($data);
```

Now, I've included recordset.php in somewhere.php to use the array stored in it. It works fine when the uploaded CSV file has 5000 lines, now if i try to upload csv with 50000 lines for example, i'm getting a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79691776 bytes)

How can I fix it or is there a possible way to achieve what i want in a more convenient way? Speaking about the performance... Should i consider the CPU of the server? I've override the memory limit and set it to -1 in somewhere.php

Comment: How much RAM is available on your server?

Comment: How can i identify it? It's remote

Comment: first of all try `phpinfo()` to check if `memory_limit` has been overridden. Tell me if you are using Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. You need to increase memory(RAM) on the server as `memory_limit` can only use memory which is available on server. And it seems that you have very low RAM available for PHP.

To Check the total RAM on Linux server:

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo','r');
  $mem = 0;
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    $pieces = array();
    if (preg_match('/^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)\skB$/', $line, $pieces)) {
      $mem = $pieces[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);

  echo "$mem kB RAM found"; ?>
```

**Source:** [get server ram with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455379/get-server-ram-with-php)

2. You should parse your CSV file in chunks & every time release occupied memory using `unset` function.