# How To Find Total Memory Usage

Tags: php

I want to be able to figure out how much total RAM is being used in total by the system - NOT JUST PHP. If a computer with 8GBs has 1GB being used, I want to be able to get these numbers and display them (1GB/8GBs).

All I can figure out is how to find how much memory a PHP script is using, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Do you mean how much memory PHP is using or how much memory the server has available? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455379/get-server-ram-with-php is useful

Comment: I doubt that PHP would natively have system sensitive data such as this available, it would be better to use another system and then creater a wrapper file to inject that value back into PHP as required

Comment: +user3783243 this works. I'll post a solution shortly. Thank you!
+Martin I know it's not very secure, but I'm not going for security right now (it's something for home networking)

Comment: memory_get_usage () -> Returns the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: +dale landry That was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used the /proc/meminfo file to get the MemTotal and MemFree values. I then subtracted the MemFree value from MemTotal to get how much memory is currently in use by the system (not PHP).

```
    function memory_usage() {
            return memory_total() - memory_free();
    }

    function memory_free() {
            $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo','r');
            $mem = 0;
            while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
                    $pieces = array();
                    if (preg_match('/^MemFree:\s+(\d+)\skB$/', $line, $pieces)) {
                            $mem = $pieces[1];
                            break;
                    }
            }
            fclose($fh);
            return $mem;
    }

    function memory_total() {
            $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo','r');
            $mem = 0;
            while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
                    $pieces = array();
                    if (preg_match('/^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)\skB$/', $line, $pieces)) {
                            $mem = $pieces[1];
                            break;
                    }
            }
            fclose($fh);
            return $mem;
    }
```